# IDA API Является ли операнд смещением

Tags: ассемблер, дизассемблирование

Я пишу плагин для IDA Pro, который добавляет ссылки к динамически определяемым смещениям вроде call eax, push eax, где eax является смещением.
Допустим, у меня есть операция push eax, как определить яляется ли eax смещением?

Comment: Если это `call eax` - это всегда смещение (адрес функции). Если, например, `push eax` - то видя только одну команду понять нельзя, только по контексту.

Comment: @insolor Если push eax яляется аргументом функции, прототип которой изветен, то Ида может сама догадаться, что это смещение. Так вот, мне нужно узнать мнение Иды используя API